# Warm SQL Backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, backup

We have a warm sql backup.  full backup nightly, txn logs shipped every so often during the day and restored.  I need to move the data files to another disk.  These DB's are in a "warm backup" state (such that I can't unmark them as read-only - "Error 5063: Database '<dbname>' is in warm standby. A warm-standby database is read-only.
") and am worried about detaching and re-attaching.

How do we obtain the "warm backup" status after detach/attach operations are complete?

Comment: Would you mind editing your "question" into a actual question?  You might get some more answers that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I know is to create a complete backup of your active database and restore this backup to a copy of the database in a 'warm backup' state. First create a backup from the active db:

```
backup database activedb to disk='somefile'
```

Then restore the backup on another sql server. If needed you can use the WITH REPLACE option to change the default storage directory

```
restore database warmbackup from disk='somefile'
       with norecovery, replace ....
```

Now you can create backups of the logs and restore them to the warmbackup with the restore log statement.

Comment: Exactly correct. We had the restore statements scripted out to be run in a batch, so I just reran those with the "replace" parameter and ta dah! All is right in the universe.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering the "warm backup" refers to the 3rd option in enterprise manager "leave database read-only and able to restore additional transaction logs" or the "WITH STANDBY" option under the "restore" command.

Comment: this answer helped me, along with this
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188696.aspx) 
and this procedure to kill all the processes using the db:
[link](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/996567-read-only-warm-standby-status.html#post3672527)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't complete the restore task , just do the restore task only for the TRANSACTOINAL LOG .Then it will be fine immediately when you finish that.